# Can my app users upload files to my Google Drive, without giving my gmail user nor password?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, file-upload, google-drive-android-api

I am new to combining Google Drive with android. 
I have succesfully made this Google Drive sample code work:

https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart

The app does these 4 steps:
1) Asks me to select a gmail account in my phone, or to add an existing one with user/password.
2) The camera opens
3) When the user takes a photo, the app opens an activity, asking me the folder within Google Drive to which I want to save the photo.
4) The photo appears in google drive.

I have an existential question that may seem dumb, but I am sure many other android developers may also be asking it:

Can users upload files to MY google drive account, without them having to input MY Google drive's user/password?
TAKE INTO ACCOUNT: Files are 2 Mb or less This is an R&D app, which means it will not be published in the Play Store, and it will be targeted to a few (20) users within the department. That said, security is relaxed.

Comment: You need use Google Driver API, first step you login and get acess token key of Google Driver API , second you store it in your code then use it for every upload file action

Comment: when you say login, do you mean the user's account or my account (where I want to store the files comming from all the users)? @GiapLee

Comment: so you want your users to be able to upload their data to your drive account? Firstly that is a really bad idea but if you were thinking of a small app for a few users then you could make a server side that connects to google drive. For example you can use server side languages like php (noone can see your code because it gets processed in the server) to connect to the drive. I think this will help you: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/php .. so basically you send request to server and server accesses your account..

Comment: @Josh Also, I don't know what the size of your files is, but you may take a look at Firebase as an alternative solution. It will handle maps of trivial object quite well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is **NO**. With Google Drive (both [GDAA](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro) and the [REST](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk) Api), the android device user identifies her/himself by selecting an existing account on a device (or adding a new one). The app than uploads / downloads objects (files/folders) to that GooDrive account.

The only way this can be accomplished is under the **REST Api (DRIVE scope)**, you let different users upload files to THEIR OWN GooDrives and share these files with your account (via your email, domain). Your account can then see the shared files. [See this.](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-sharing)

Obviously, there is still a possibility of creating a specific google account for your application/problem and let all the users share this account with a password known to all of them (but it is not what you were asking).

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is **Yes** it is possible !!! the app user can directly upload the files to your drive without username and password of that account...which means u have to share the access token of that particular drive account to that app.

Using that access token(credential - **setAccessToken**("place your access token here") we can create a service and upload the file.